# How to position a form above an element

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a wall that shows messages from users in two columns. Each message is a div box.
I have given the id of each box the id of the message.

When a user clicks edit for a message a form should be place on the page using Ajax.

The form is as wide as the two message columns.

If a user edits a message that is on the left column I can insert the form before this message to the left.

However if the message is on the right I need to insert the form at the beginning of the left message and above it.

How can I do this using jquery?

Rails 3  js.erb

Comment: Why dont you just reserve some place for this form somewhere on the page? Then you can just show the form for particular message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I miss something but if you know the id of the left message you can easily use

```
$('#edit_link').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getyourform",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#left_message_id').before(data);
        }
    });
}
```